# Ruby printf"%-*.*s" problems

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use this line of code here:

`longest = twoOfArray.inject(0) {|memo,word| memo > word.length ? memo : word.length}`,

and put it into this printf on this line like this:

`twoOfArray.each {|k, v| puts "%-*.*s" % [longest] + " " + '*'*v }`

However, it gives me the error:

`%': too few arguments (ArgumentError)`

Does this mean that something is wrong with my `longest` variable? Or is my syntax wrong? I cant seem to fix the problem. Does anyone see whats wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The format string `"%-*.*s" expects three arguments: two numbers (one for each`*`) and a string. Your array only contains a single argument.

Comment: Alright thank you, I did not know the *'s were placeholders. The `longest` variable as of right now should return the length of the longest word within the array. Would you happen to know how I would modify the `longest` variable to return both the larger of the current maximum and the length of the current word?

Answer (score -1):

```
hash = {"it"=>3, "was"=>3, "the"=>3, "of"=>2, "times"=>2}

words_array = hash.keys
longest_word = words_array.max_by {|word| word.length}
max_len = longest_word.size

words_array.each do |word|
  number = hash[word]
  str = "#{'*' * (max_len - number)}#{word}#{'*' * number}"
  puts str
end

--output:--
**it***
**was***
**the***
***of**
***times**
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I can't see what your saying, I literally started ruby a couple days ago. Are you saying my line should look like this :    `twoOfArray.each {|k, v| puts "%-*.*s" % [k, twoOfArray.max, twoOfArray.max.size] + " " + '*'*v }`

Comment: Is twoOfArray an array or a hash?

Comment: Instead of posting what you did, post your array, or preferably a small example of your array, and post exactly what the output should be--do not describe the output, post the exact output you want.

Comment: When you say that longest should return both x and y, that means that longest is going to be something containing two values, which is an Array.  Is that really what you want?  But like I said, your descriptions and code are non-sensical, so just post your Array/Hash/whatever, and the exact output you want.

Comment: The hash/Array/whatever : `{"it"=>3, "was"=>3, "the"=>3, "of"=>2, "times"=>2} {"of"=>3, "it"=>2, "was"=>2, "the"=>2} {"it"=>3, "was"=>3, "the"=>2, "of"=>2} {"the"=>3, "of"=>2, "it"=>2, "was"=>2} {"we"=>2, "had"=>2, "before"=>2, "us"=>2} {"we"=>2, "were"=>2, "all"=>2, "going"=>2, "direct"=>2} {"the"=>2, "period"=>2} {"its"=>2}` Output should be the word, and a number of asteriks depending on what the value of the key is example Period: ** it: ***. the longest variable is needed to determine the width.

Comment: @Lack, See my revised answer, but it's not clear to me what all that garbage you posted is supposed to represent.